# Which metastore does Hive use?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

Before start, I need to say that I am new to the concept of Big Data and Apache Hive. When following [this post](https://techblost.com/how-to-install-hive-on-mac-with-homebrew/) to install Hive, I saw that they create another database called `metastore`. After installing and configuring successfully, I was able to perform some basic commands (create database, table, load data, etc) in Hive shell (by typing `./hive` in Hive's `bin` folder). 
 When I check in mysql database, there appears 2 new databases: `hive` & `metastore`, and I believe `metastore` database is where the metadata of tables, databases are stored. However, it is not what I expected. Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QXlt.png). 
My question is if I have installed Hive successfully or not, and what is the purpose of those 2 databases? 
P/s: I have searched for Hive metastore and there are 3 different modes, but I am not sure if that is my case in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Hive Metastore will use Apache Derby.

It's recommended you change this to be Postgres, Mysql, or Oracle.

The mysql command `CREATE database metastore;` doesn't mean anything specific. The hive-site.xml sets the JDBC connection string where the metastore database is configured, and you can provide any name you want.

Similar for `hive`.

Unclear what you expected in those databases for tables, but it's metadata, not actual HDFS records

Comment: Thank you Sir, btw I have figured out the reason I have 2 databases. In [the post](https://techblost.com/how-to-install-hive-on-mac-with-homebrew/), they create a new database called `metastore`, but when they set up Hive configuration, they write: "<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>". That's why `metastore` database has nothing inside. @@